# Evernote Thumbnails

Tags: php, evernote

I am writing a simple application that lists all the Notes via the Evernote API. I have successfully authenticated and retrieved a list of Notes.

Now I am trying to get Note thumbnails via the Evernote API. I have read their [documentation here][1]. I tried a POST request, but for some reason it's not working. Obviously, I am doing something wrong. Can you please give me a quick, simple, example?

**Example Code:**

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.evernote.com/shard/s226/thm/note/64c08998-0bd3-4964-83fd-73a3baaf53cd.jpg?size=40">
    <input type="submit" value="View Thumbnail">
</form>
```

I just set the form method to POST and action to `Note Thumbnail`. The note thumbnail works when you log in yourself into the Evernote website, but otherwise, it just says access denied. I am new to Evernote API, so I tried the above code just to see if that works or not.

**Correct Example Code:**

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.evernote.com/shard/s226/thm/note/64c08998-0bd3-4964-83fd-73a3baaf53cd.jpg?size=40">
    <input type="hidden" name="auth" value="{authentication token}">
    <input type="submit" value="View Thumbnail">
</form>
```

Comment: Post your code so we can help you fix it.

Comment: I have added example code. Thanks Uby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to include the authentication token in the request.

Comment: Thanks Mustafa. I'll appreciate if you could please put some quick code example with dummy auth token string?

Comment: Example is here : http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/cloud/chapters/thumbnails.php